# disconnect to wifi programmatically

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

Could I disconnect to wifi programmatically in Cocoa?

Comment: nope, you can't do that, thank god :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Mac, see the CoreWLAN Framework. Specifically the [disassociate method of CWInterface](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/CWInterface_h/Classes/CWInterface/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CWInterface/disassociate). On the iPhone (since you tagged this cocoa-touch), I believe this operation is restricted (ie, no supported API exists for applications to configure network connectivity).